# Issue with ADF DataFlow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have set in Source activity -> Source Options 'Filter by last modified' and have put this addDays(currentUTC('CET'), -10), but when I go to 'Data Preview', it gives me an error - 'An error occurred, please view notification for more details'. When I removed the 'last modified date' feature, there is no 'Data Preview' problem. What could be the reason?
And subDays also doesn't work

[image]

[image]

Comment: instead of `addDays` try `subDays` and value 10

Comment: This error message is generic. Could you add the error message that you are getting in data preview also?

Comment: unfortunately, this is the only message I get

Comment: Even in data preview also, are you getting this message?

Comment: I'm getting this error as a notification in the upper right corner, and in the data preview it doesn't show me anything

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is fine and reason for the error seems to be there are no files within that modified file. So, check the **Allow no files found** in the source options to avoid the error. Here I have added a column **filepath** to get the filename as well.

[image]

This will ensure empty data when we don't have any files within that date range.

Result when files are within range:

[image]

**Result when there are no files in the required date range:**

[image]